# How to load a keras model saved as .pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'd like to load a keras model that i've trained and saved it as **.pb**.
 Here's the code, 
[image]

Am using a jupyter notebook. 
The model is successfully saved as **saved_model.pb** under the same directory. But the code is unable to access it. 
Can anybody see to it, how can i access this keras model that's saved in **.pb** extension. 
I checked at several other places for solution but no luck.

Model is saved at **model/saved_model.pb**. 
I've taken out the **.pb** file and placed it in the same directory where my code file exists.

Comment: You are saving it with name `model` and loading it with name `saved_model.pb`. Maybe, this is the problem?

Comment: Not exactly, it's actually saved in model folder ...
model > saved_model.pb
So i have taken out the pb file from there and pasted it in the same directory where my code file exists.

Comment: The book I'm following uses `model.save("my_keras_model.h5")` to save the model **named** as `my_keras_model.h5`. And, then, it is loaded like this: `keras.models.load_model("my_keras_model.h5")`

Comment: Yes the keras model can be saved as h5. I was experimenting if it can be saved under .pb extension and can be used. To my surpise, it was saved but unable to load it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function `tf.keras.models.load_model` load a `SavedModel` into a `tf.keras` -model. The argument of the function is path to a saved model.

So try `model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')`

Comment: Oh okay it works, now how to access the model, i mean, if i type model.summary(), it's not showing anything.

Comment: What if you load the model with `tf.keras.models.load_model('model')` and run `model.summary()` after that?

Answer (score 7):

You should load all model folder instead of loading .pb file.
If you save model to `'./_models/vgg50_finetune'` (I used this path in my project), you get folder vgg50_finetune with two .pb files (keras_metadata.pb and saved_model.pb) and two subfolders (assets and variables).
The only thing you should do is use this code:
`model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./_models/vgg50_finetune')`
And you can both train model or use it for prediction.