# How to load a SavedModel downloaded from TFHub as a Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am really new to tensorflow and I am trying to figure out how to load a SavedModel downloaded from TFHub as a Keras model.

I downloaded a SavedModel from https://tfhub.dev/google/LaBSE/2. I was able to load the model in my code using `tf.saved_model.load()`. However, when I tried to load the model using `tf.keras.models.load_model`, I got the following error

> IndexError: list index (0) out of range

And idea how i can load or convert the model to a Keras model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the *Example Use* part in the Hub? Are the example codes there working for you?
Please try the below snippet for loading the model directly from the Hub:

```
hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/LaBSE/2")
```

Because yours is a Hub model, the above line should work for you.

---

However, if you'd like to directly convert the SavedModel (.pb) into a Keras model, then please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63147104/12852066).